# Запускать таймер при скролле. javascript

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Может кто подсказать? Пишу скрипт, который запускает таймер, когда человек проскроллил экран до определенного блока. Таймер отсчитывает 10 сек. Если в теч. этого времени человек прокрутил этот блок (неважно в каком направлении), то счетчик обнуляется, а если изучал блок все 10 сек., то появляется другой блок. Так вот, собственно, вопрос. С правильной ли стороны я изначально начал подходить к вопросу, и почему не работает clearInterval при выходе с блока ?

```js
// function printNumbers(from, to) {
//   let current = from;
//   const timerBox = document.querySelector('.timer');
//   let timerId = setInterval(function() {
//     timerBox.innerHTML = current;
//     if (current == to) {
//       clearInterval(timerId);
//       
//     }
//     current++;
//   }, 1000);
// }

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  
let counter = 0;
let currentNum = 0;
const timerBox = document.querySelector('.timer');
const element = document.querySelector('.screen3');
const elemHid = document.querySelector('.screen-hidden'); 

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  
  const elemPosition = {
    top: window.pageYOffset + element.getBoundingClientRect().top, 
    bottom: window.pageYOffset + element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom 
  }

  const windowPosition = {
    top: window.pageYOffset, 
    bottom: window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight 
  }
  
  if( elemPosition.top < windowPosition.bottom && elemPosition.bottom > windowPosition.top && counter == 0 ){

    let timerId = setInterval(function(){
      timerBox.innerHTML = currentNum;
      if(currentNum == 10){
        clearInterval(timerId);
      }
      currentNum++;
    }, 1000);
      
    counter = 1;
    
  } 
  else {
      clearInterval(timerId);
  }
  
});

});
```

```css
.section{ height: 700px; }
.screen-hidden{display: none;}
.timer{ position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; display: inline-block; padding: 20px; background: black; color: white; }
```

```html
<div class="timer">0</div>
<section class="section screen1" style="background-color: red;"></section>
<section class="section screen2" style="background-color: yellow;"></section>
<section class="section screen3" style="background-color: green;"></section>
<section class="section screen-hidden" style="background-color: black;"></section>
<section class="section screen4" style="background-color: blue;"></section>
<section class="section screen5" style="background-color: pink;"></section>
```

Comment: Пока вы скролируете туда-сюда вокруг вашей секции, в браузере происходит куча scroll-событий, и все эти события запускают кучу таймеров одновременно.

Comment: К тому же переменная timerId объявляется в одном блоке, а используется в другом, в котором она видна.

Comment: Почитйте про intersectionObserve(вроде так, точно не помню)

Comment: Да, действительно, intersectionObserve выручило) С ним гораздо проще все оказалось. Спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вдруг кому нужно будет

```js
// таймер начинает работать только когда красный блок находится в зоне вьюпорта, иначе останавливается и сбрасывается в начало

window.addEventListener('load', event => {
  let timer;
  const timerBox = document.querySelector('.timer');
  let currentNum = 10;
  const box = document.querySelector('.item');
  const boxHidden = document.querySelector('.item-black');
  let prevRatio = 0.0;

  function countdown(){
    timerBox.innerHTML = currentNum;
    currentNum--;
    if(currentNum < 0){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      boxHidden.style.display = 'block';
    } else{
      timer = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    } 
  }
  
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {

    entries.forEach(entry => {
      let curRatio = entry.intersectionRatio;

      if(curRatio > prevRatio){

        entry.target.style.background = `red`;
        countdown();

      } else{

        entry.target.style.background = `transparent`;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        currentNum = 10;

      }

      prevRatio = curRatio;
    })
  }, { threshold: 0.1 });

  observer.observe(box);
});
```

```css
 .item {
   width: 640px;
   height: 480px;
   outline: 2px solid;
   margin: 100vh auto;
}
.item-black{width: 100px; height: 100px; background: black; display: none; color: #FFF;}
.timer{ position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; display: inline-block; padding: 20px; background: black; color: white; }
```

```html
<div class="timer">10</div>
<div class="item">
  если долго разглядывать этот блок...
  <div class="item-black"> то появляется этот</div>
</div>
```